# How can I minimize the code lines using (for each)

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach, swiper.js

#### swiper one

```
var swiperCurrent;

var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container-1', {
    init: false,
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination-1',
    nextButton: '.swiper-button-next-1',
    prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev-1',
    slidesPerView: 3,
    centeredSlides: true,
    paginationClickable: true,
    initialSlide: 2,
    spaceBetween: 22,
    breakpoints: {
        992: {
            slidesPerView: 1,
            spaceBetween: 10
        }
    },
    runCallbacksOnInit:true
});

function showSliderContent2(idx) {
    $('._ooredoo_banner_content_1> div').hide(0);
    $('._ooredoo_banner_content_1> div:eq('+ idx +')').fadeIn(200)
}

swiper.on('init', function (el) {
    showSliderContent(el.activeIndex);
});

swiper.on('transitionEnd', function (el) {
    if(swiperCurrent !== el.activeIndex){
        showSliderContent(el.activeIndex);
        swiperCurrent = el.activeIndex;
    }
});

swiper.init();
```

#### swiper two

```
var swiperCurrent2;

var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container-2, {
    init: false,
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination-2',
    nextButton: '.swiper-button-next-2',
    prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev-2',
    slidesPerView: 3,
    centeredSlides: true,
    paginationClickable: true,
    initialSlide: 2,
    spaceBetween: 22,
    breakpoints: {
        992: {
            slidesPerView: 1,
            spaceBetween: 10
        }
    },
    runCallbacksOnInit:true
});

function showSliderContent2(idx) {
    $('._ooredoo_banner_content_2> div').hide(0);
    $('._ooredoo_banner_content_2> div:eq('+ idx +')').fadeIn(200)
}

swiper.on('init', function (el) {
    showSliderContent2(el.activeIndex);
});

swiper.on('transitionEnd', function (el) {
    if(swiperCurrent2 !== el.activeIndex){
        showSliderContent2(el.activeIndex);
        swiperCurrent2 = el.activeIndex;
    }
});

swiper.init();
```

#### swiper three

```
var swiperCurrent3;

var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container-3’, {
    init: false,
    pagination: '.swiper-pagination-3',
    nextButton: '.swiper-button-next-3',
    prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev-3',
    slidesPerView: 3,
    centeredSlides: true,
    paginationClickable: true,
    initialSlide: 2,
    spaceBetween: 22,
    breakpoints: {
        992: {
            slidesPerView: 1,
            spaceBetween: 10
        }
    },
    runCallbacksOnInit:true
});

function showSliderContent3(idx) {
    $('._ooredoo_banner_content_3> div').hide(0);
    $('._ooredoo_banner_content_3> div:eq('+ idx +')').fadeIn(200)
}

swiper.on('init', function (el) {
    showSliderContent3(el.activeIndex);
});

swiper.on('transitionEnd', function (el) {
    if(swiperCurrent3 !== el.activeIndex){
        showSliderContent3(el.activeIndex);
        swiperCurrent3 = el.activeIndex;
    }
});

swiper.init();
```

Comment: what is your question exactly?

Comment: It seems like what you want to know is how to create these three swipers (and maybe more) without having to duplicate all that code? Remember that in JavaScript you can return functions as values from other functions (and pass them around). So I'd look at the similarities between the three (and there are many) and then use the principals of [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) and function creation to make a utility method that took in arguments for any dissimilar value.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following (untested) code might help: All I did was to factor out the common code into a reusable function and use template strings to fill in the missing parts, then `map` that function over the `1`, `2`, and `3` partial ids.  This means we no longer need the `2` and `3` suffixes on some of the variables; they are only available inside the closures generated by the callback to `map`.

There are likely bugs in this, either reusing something I shouldn't or the reverse: making something dynamic that doesn't have to be.  In the first case, if you can continue to use the `id` to distinguish it, great.  If not, you might need one ore more additional variables, and the `map` statement will have to get a little more complex.

```
const makeSwiper = (id) => {
    var swiperCurrent;

    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container-2', {
        init: false,
        pagination: `.swiper-pagination-${id}`,
        nextButton: `.swiper-button-next-${id}`,
        prevButton: `.swiper-button-prev-${id}`,
        slidesPerView: 3,
        centeredSlides: true,
        paginationClickable: true,
        initialSlide: 2,
        spaceBetween: 22,
        breakpoints: {
            992: {
                slidesPerView: 1,
                spaceBetween: 10
            }
        },
        runCallbacksOnInit:true
    });

    function showSliderContent(idx) {
        $(`._ooredoo_banner_content_${id}> div`).hide(0);
        $(`._ooredoo_banner_content_${id}> div:eq(${idx})`).fadeIn(200)
    }

    swiper.on('init', function (el) {
        showSliderContent(el.activeIndex);
    });

    swiper.on('transitionEnd', function (el) {
        if(swiperCurrent !== el.activeIndex){
            showSliderContent(el.activeIndex);
            swiperCurrent = el.activeIndex;
        }
    });

    return swiper
}

const swipers = [1, 2, 3].map(makeSwiper)
```